# Where's "integrated windows authentication" IIS5 checkbox equivalent in IIS in Win7?

Tags: iis-7

In IIS 5 & 6 there's a tab called "Directory Security" where one can define the authentication access and check the "Integrated windows authentication" checkbox.

I can't find the same options in IIS Manager in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://cosier.wordpress.com/2007/08/23/adding-windows-authentication-provider-into-iis-7-on-vista/) was helpful. Very annoying that Microsoft changed the options so much that what used to take me 5 seconds to do in previous versions made me search for an hour and to discover that windows authentication option is nowhere to be displayed unless the provider is installed and that it's off by default.

Comment: While you're in there, you should pretty much check off all the boxes that relate to IIS because it's a development box (Windows 7). You can leave refinement of security principles to later when you have a deployment box (and best to practice in a lab computer on a VM so you can flush and recycle configs).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link. Helped me a lot. **[Enabling Windows Authentication on IIS 7.5](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication).**
Microsoft really need to do some easy documentation before making so heavy changes.

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 is structured quite differently from IIS 5 or 6.  This [link](http://codesnip.net/iis7-integrated-windows-authentication-win-2008) describes the process for enabling Integrated Windows Authentication (and other authentication methods) and includes some helpful images.

Comment: The docs seems to be for Windows 2008. I can't find the server manager or how to add role services in windows 7.